# java.util.NoSuchElementException - Exception in thread "main" error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm not too sure about this error as I cannot figure out what's going on. Through the debugger, I can see that the file is been successfully read, but on the last index, I get an error. Anyone know why?

```
try {
    txtin = new Scanner(gameFile);
    //String line;
    while(txtin.hasNext()) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            Grid[i] = txtin.next();
        }

    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if (txtin != null)
        txtin.close();
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `txtin.hasNext()` checks if there is *one* next element, but after checking it you are entering into inner loop which tries to read 15 tokens, which apparently are not as many.

Comment: Take a few minutes to read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to debug your own code.

Comment: @Pshemo How would I fix this? Would I have to remove the `Grid[i] = txtin.next();`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks.

Comment: @GiftoDumbo You should remove the `for` loop and find a different way to add to your `Grid` array. I see at least two options: use a `List` instead of an array. 2. Write the code to make your own counter without a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `Iterator#next()`, it moves the underlying cursor forward. You are calling `txtin.next()` in a for loop for 15 times. There may be a case where there are less than 15 token and the cursor went to a place that doesn't have **such element** Thus `NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
while(txtin.hasNext()) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    Grid[i] = txtin.next();
  }
}
```

with

```
int i=0;
while(txtin.hasNext()) {
  Grid[i++] = txtin.next();
}
```

For the reasons described by Gagan Chouhan.